# factory_bot_rails failed to install after bundle install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

Trying to install the `factory_bot_rails` gem, but running into this after executing `bundle install`:

```
There was an error parsing `Gemfile`: Undefined local variable or method `‘factory_bot_rails’' for Gemfile. Bundler cannot continue.
```

My rvm is up to date...what exactly is the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: check if `source "http://rubygems.org"` line is missing in your Gemfile.

Comment: `‘factory_bot_rails’` don't use curly quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is how the gem is wrote.

Just type on a console in the project's root directory:

```
gem install factory_bot_rails
```

or put inside your Gem file

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'factory_bot_rails'
end
```

After type:

```
bundle install
```

source: https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot_rails [enter link description here](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot_rails)